# Creating a custom upload progress bar

Tags: php, jquery, upload

I have seen all the upload progress bar plugins, widgets, etc. – they all suck. They're either too bulky with too much useless code or they don't work.

What I want to know is where I can read up on how to display an easy upload progress indicator. Most browsers have a status progress bar on them below, but it isn't very professional to use just that when dealing with clients.

How does the browser do it? I want to know the internals of how the browser works with for indicating the status of something uploading so that maybe I can make something using PHP & jquery.

Thanks.

Comment: Indeed they all do, because the amount of information that the browser provides to the web page is (intentionally) limited. The browser progress bar works on a lower level than the in-page bars, thus it has more data about the state of the page, thus it Sucks Less (TM).

If you want to build your own, better in-page progress bar, go for it, by all means.

Comment: And IMHO the browser bar sucks, too - AFAIK only Chrome and Opera show you how much data is uploaded when doing a POST request.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want to use PHP, I'd start with the [uploadprogress extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress/) (PHP doesn't, by default, give you any data about until the upload is completed; this extension provides such server-side functionality). Note that it **requires PHP 5.2+** and can be picky about configuration options. Also see its [commentary and demo](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2006/09/28/upload-progress-meter-extension-for-php-5-2.html) and [troubleshooting hints](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2009/03/31/upload-progress-meter-common-issues-and-some-answers.html)). A short overview available in PHP documentation [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#71564).

Using the extension, you can get some stats on the upload; then you can poll the server through AJAX and update some sort of progress bar.

To be a bit more specific:

- get an unique identifier for the form, and include it in a hidden field
- the upload should run in an IFRAME - some browsers won't allow DOM updates to the same page that is running the upload
- poll the server via AJAX (using the identifier to specify which upload you're interested in) and parse the result (IIRC, you'll get something like "bytes_uploaded => 123, content-length=> 1000")
- update your progress bar (the way you display it is up to you, I use "x% done" plus a graphical bar)
- redirect whole page when form uploaded OK

(Oh, and btw, check PHP's upload_max_filesize and post_max_size settings, as both limit the maximum upload size)

Answer (score 2):

There is no **reliable** method to get the progress of a file upload using JavaScript.  Support for the [XMLHttpRequest `upload.onprogress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#section_13) event is missing in many browsers, even with HTML5, you will inevitably need to turn to Flash, or another method of file upload.

After asking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292160/), I eventually settled on using [plupload](http://plupload.org) for my uploading needs.

Comment: Indeed, no reliable way when using *only* JS; if you can ask the server "are we there yet?", things become easier.

Answer (score 1):

`Javascript/Ecmascript` cannot mess with native browser functionalitys (which uses `C/C++` mostly along with `OS APIs` which access `TCP/UDP` sockets.

To display a progressbar with `JS` you need serverfeedback. That can be accomplished by using a server `polling` like [COMET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) for instance.
But at this point, it's never that accurate like the browser buildin progressbar. It will change maybe with `HTML5 WebSockets`.

To have an accurate result, you need a continuous connection. You can `fake` and `gild` the client-server request delay, but it's still there. I don't know exactly how `Flash` handles this issues, but I guess it also does not have connection-oriented stream (Correct me if I'm wrong here).

Comment: Flash knows how many bytes it has transmitted / how many it needs to, and fires events while the connection is open and transmitting.  This is something that the `xhr.upload.onprogress` event (loosely supported in Firefox 3.5) is supposed to provide, but I never got it working reliably.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isnt what you're looking for but I've been using [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) for uploads recently and it seems pretty good plus doesnt rely on flash or html5 exclusively

example:

---

- the url is the proccessing page (php
  file)
- container = the parent div or form that that the upload button lives in (its really important to set this - there are some example of how you can attach things to certain actions that plupload does. for example below you can see i have attached `uploader.start();`to the `uploader.start();` hook.
- you should also be able to see how i've made a custom upload progress bar, by attaching to the upload progress hook

---

worth asking questions on the forum on the plupload site if you get stuck, they're good at answering them!

```
$(function(){
    //plupload
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash',
        browse_button : 'pickfiles',
        container : 'form_2',
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        url : '<?php echo SITE_ROOT ?>plupload/upload.php',
        //resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90},
        flash_swf_url : '<?php echo SITE_ROOT ?>plupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
        filters : [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"}
        ]
    });


uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
    uploader.start();
});

uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
    if(file.percent < 100 && file.percent >= 1){
        $('#progress_bar div').css('width', file.percent+'%');
    }
    else{
        $('#progress_bar').fadeOut(600);
    }                               
});
```

Comment: thanks i love plupload looks really cool. but how did you get it to link with the php page to upload? i cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: i've updated my answer with the script i use for calling plupload.

Comment: excepting that plupload doesn't work on msie without flash?!-(